# Use REST to make Item Private in DSPace

Tags: dspace

I have approximately 4000 items I need to make private in the repository. Is there a way I can do this using the REST API?

The edit this item and make private in the XMLUI seems to be not very feasible with the number of items I have.

Comment: Do you need to do this large number of updates once only or is it an ongoing need?

Comment: I want to do it once. And there might be need in the future as we are migrating lots of data from an old system which is not dspace.